# Difficulty in merging two dataframes on two columns, ticker and date

Tags: python, dataframe

I have reviewed numerous responses to this type of question.  I am trying to merge two files by columns and the dataframes only share ticker and date, so if I set `how='left'`, it shows data for the `df_US[US_columns]` and the header columns for `df_SEDOL_ESG[ESG_columns]` but no data for `df_SEDOL_ESG[ESG_columns]`.

Likewise, if you set `how = 'right'`, it shows the reverse. I have tried setting `how = 'outer'` and that does not merge the dataframes but lists them separately.

Below the code, I have attached the sample dataframe and dtypes  since I wanted to insure that the date column was in a datetime format. Any guidance is appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

path0 = 'K:/QuantTest/Data/ESG/'
path1 = 'K:/QuantTest/Data/US/'


def US_ESG():    

    df_US = pd.read_csv(path1 + 'df_US_weekly_expectationt.csv', dtype={'ticker':'str'})
    df_US.rename(columns = {'Date': 'date'}, inplace = True)
    df_US['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_US['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors = 'coerce')

    df_SEDOL_ESG = pd.read_csv(path0 + 'SEDOL_ESGt.csv', dtype = {'ticker':'str'})
    df_SEDOL_ESG.rename(columns = {'Ticker':'ticker'}, inplace=True)
    df_SEDOL_ESG['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_SEDOL_ESG['date'], format='%m/%d/%Y', errors = 'coerce')

    US_columns = ['ticker', 'date', 'volume', 'closing_price']
    ESG_columns = ['ticker', 'date','AllCategories_Insight','AllCategories_CategoryVolumeTTM']

    df_US_ESG = df_US[US_columns].merge(df_SEDOL_ESG[ESG_columns], how='left', on = ['ticker', 'date'])

    df_US_ESG.to_csv(path0 + 'US_ESGt.csv', index = False)


if __name__ == "__main__":

   US_ESG()
```

Comment: I might think on option in merge is not working for your case. Are all the data in ticker and data cols identical for each row? Can you provide some rows of data for 2 df?

Comment: ticker date volume closing_price
A          12/28/2018 2445101.5 65.96
AABA       12/28/2018 7113085.5 58.35
AAP        12/28/2018 1066813.625 155.46
AAPL       12/28/2018 43182216 156.23
ABC        12/28/2018 1286497.125 73.96

Comment: OrganizationTvlId ISIN Ownership SEDOL Ticker Company Name InstrumentCountry Sector Industry date AllCategories_Insight Materiality_Insight AllCategories_CategoryVolumeTTM Materiality_CategoryVolumeTTM
0002c46f-98ff-457e-83e0-47b466746572 US55027E1029 Public 2572109 A Luminex Corp. US Health Care Biotechnology 12/28/2018 56.12375097 58.27797253 4 3
0002c46f-98ff-457e-83e0-47b466746572 US55027E1029 Public 2572109 AABA Luminex Corp. US Health Care Biotechnology 12/28/2018 56.37543414 58.48117502 4 3

Comment: Above, I have attached the dataframes.  The data in df_US is a subset of the df_SEDOL_ESG. Also the data, excluding the ticker and date, are different in both of the dataframes and that is the reason that I am trying to merge them.  I need to use df_US['volume'] and df_US['closing_price'] to calculate a new item with AllCategory_CategoryVolumeTTM. Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge 2 dataframes, like this. on parametars are used as join kyes. [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-or-named-series-joining-merging)

```
# before
df_US_ESG = df_US[US_columns].merge(df_SEDOL_ESG[ESG_columns], how='left', on = ['ticker', 'date'])

# after
df_US_ESG = pd.maerge(df_US[US_columns], df_SEDOL_ESG[ESG_columns], on = ['ticker', 'date'])
```

My reproduction is like this. Hope this help.

```
# df1.csv
ticker,date,volume,closing_price
A,12/28/2018,2445101.5,65.96
AABA,12/28/2018,7113085.5,58.35
AAP,12/28/2018,1066813.625,155.46
AAPL,12/28/2018,43182216,156.23
ABC,12/28/2018,1286497.125,73.96

# df2.csv

OrganizationTvlId,ISIN,Ownership,SEDOL,ticker,Company_Name,InstrumentCountry,Sector,Industry,date,AllCategories_Insight,Materiality_Insight,AllCategories_CategoryVolumeTTM,Materiality_CategoryVolumeTTM
0002c46f-98ff-457e-83e0-47b466746572,US55027E1029,Public,2572109,A,Luminex_Corp.,US,Health_Care,Biotechnology,12/28/2018,56.12375097,58.27797253,4,3
0002c46f-98ff-457e-83e0-47b466746572,US55027E1029,Public,2572109,AABA,Luminex_Corp.,US,Health_Care,Biotechnology,12/28/2018,56.37543414,58.48117502,4,3

# python
df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv'
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['ticker', 'date'])
print(df)

# output
ticker  date    volume  closing_price   OrganizationTvlId   ISIN    Ownership   SEDOL   Company_Name    InstrumentCountry   Sector  Industry    AllCategories_Insight   Materiality_Insight AllCategories_CategoryVolumeTTM Materiality_CategoryVolumeTTM
0   A   12/28/2018  2445101.5   65.96   0002c46f-98ff-457e-83e0-47b466746572    US55027E1029    Public  2572109 Luminex_Corp.   US  Health_Care Biotechnology   56.123751   58.277973   4   3
1   AABA    12/28/2018  7113085.5   58.35   0002c46f-98ff-457e-83e0-47b466746572    US55027E1029    Public  2572109 Luminex_Corp.   US  Health_Care Biotechnology   56.375434   58.481175   4   3
```

Comment: Shimo, thank you for your assistance. I am getting an empty data when I use the code that you suggested.Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ticker, date, volume, closing_price, AllCategories_Insight, AllCategories_CategoryVolumeTTM]
Index: []

Comment: Here is the result when I use how='outer'ticker date volume closing_price AllCategories_Insight AllCategories_CategoryVolumeTTM
A          12/28/2018 2445101.5 65.96  
AABA       12/28/2018 7113085.5 58.35  
AAP        12/28/2018 1066813.625 155.46  
AAPL       12/28/2018 43182216 156.23  
ABC        12/28/2018 1286497.125 73.96  
A 12/28/2018   56.12375097 4
AABA 12/28/2018   56.37543414 4
AAP 12/28/2018   56.62049621 4
AAPL 12/28/2018   56.85911136 4
ABC 12/28/2018   57.0914492 4
LMNX 12/28/2018   56.80139111 5

Comment: So I can not figure out why the two dataframes are not merging.  I even defined the two dataframes and used df1 and df2 as your example, and still no resolution.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I found a solution ```df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  on=['ticker', 'date'],how='outer', validate = 'one_to_many', indicator=True, left_index = True, right_index = True)```ticker date volume closing_price AllCategories_Insight AllCategories_CategoryVolumeTTM _merge
A          12/28/2018 2445101.5 65.96 56.12375097 4 both
AABA       12/28/2018 7113085.5 58.35 56.37543414 4 both
AAP        12/28/2018 1066813.625 155.46 56.62049621 4 both
AAPL       12/28/2018 43182216 156.23 56.85911136 4 both
ABC        12/28/2018 1286497.125 73.96 57.0914492 4 both
LMNX 12/28/2018   56.80139111 5 right_only